# Load Error for Ruby on Rails mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

Nubie at Ruby on Rails so I wanted to build a "Hello World" style of app to get familiar with RoR.  The app I chose, along with tutorial on installation, was Dave Berube's "checkbook" app as in http://www.redhat.com/magazine/025nov06/features/ruby/

Yes it is from 2006 and maybe I have bumped into my errors because RoR has moved on through the years.   Anyway, I get errors similar to banditKing with his app on 20th Sept., and many others; I get a persistent error as below.

When I ran RoR without creating my first app, it displayed the initial splash screen which effectively told me to "get working and create sites!" so that was a good start :-)

[running "rails generate migrate InitialSchema" to begin generating the application framework.]

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

My environment:

RH Enterprise Linux version 6, 64-bit

```
[root@svr checkbookapp]# which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 14
Server version: 5.1.69 Source distribution

[root@svr checkbookapp]# which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
[root@svr checkbookapp]# ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rails version is 4.0.0

```
[root@svr checkbookapp]# gem list | grep mysql
mysql (2.9.1)
mysql2 (0.3.13)
```

Start of my app's Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'mysql2'
...
```

I have added the library path to MySQL path into my .bash_profile as done by banditKing but that has not resolved this error.   Have tried re-installing mysql2 gem several times and doing numerous "bundle install" operations.   Downloaded and installed the connector 6.1 from the MySQL site and yum install'd the share and the development versions without any difference.

Comment: try this one "yum install rubygem-bundler" then bundle install

Answer (score 0):

Try updating RubyGems with `gem update --system`. You should get something like version 2.x. There's a bug with RubyGems 1.8.x on Ruby 2.0 installing gems with c extentions (like mysql2 and nokogiri).

Comment: In fact I started over and along the way did exactly that (gem update --system) so I suspect that fixed it.   Kind regards, Denis